# mat-checkbox v15 not working: not change checked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use mat-checkbox from Material Angular V15.2.8 but when click on checkbox not any change of value and checked.

html:

```
<mat-checkbox  [checked]="checked">Text</mat-checkbox>
```

ts:

```
 checked = false;
```

I tried a lot to search and solve the problem, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

use this:

html:

```
   <mat-checkbox   [checked]="checked" (click)="checkBoxChange()"  >Text</mat-checkbox>
```

ts:

```
 checkBoxChange(){ 
    this.checked = !this.checked; 
  }
```

Comment: this works. I'd add to make sure that you are NOT wrapping in mat-form-field

Answer (score 0):

you have a one-way binding `[checked]="checked"` if you want to use a two-way binding -when you check/uncheck the checkbox change the variable-, use [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" >Text</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Rest assured that this was the first thing I tried and it didn't work.. . The only way that worked is the answer below

Comment: @SaeedAhmadian, remember that you need import FormsModule to use ngModel, and you need declare a variable called checked in your .ts, see the most simple example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmukxf-snnucj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html). See also that you don't use checked, only ngModel

Comment: I try it but not working... I think there is a bug in the material

Comment: @SaeedAhmadian, check if you have a variable called also "checked" (try change the name checked by, e.g. "checkedVariable"). I know that the stackblitz version of material angular is not the last one but should be work :(